# Old web page with Bootstrap 3.3.4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, bootstrap-4

Im working on my old web page that has the old version of Bootstrap 3.3.4.
Web page was created 2-3 years ago. I changed some minor things, content etc. and page worked perfectly fine 1 week ago. Today I again ran web page through XAMPP and nothing was as It should be. Its like there is no bootstrap on the page at all (I used CDN). There are no grids, content is not positioned right but overall styling is still the same. Im a beginner at web development, but by the looks of the errors, I speculate that Bootstrap 3.3.4 was removed. Is this the case? What should I do? I would prefere to use the old Bootstrap as It worked perfectly 1 week ago. Is that possible or how to upgrade? 
Do I just change CDN with new Bootstrap and go through whole page and change all classes or is there any easy way?  [image: Error messages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this version is up and running (https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css) you could try to set https:// to your location.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I realised I was looking through my local files and not through XAMPP.